# Cell division - meiosis

Tags: human-biology, genetics

Really confused. How many chromosomes pairs do humans have in their sex cells? How many single chromosomes do humans have in their sex cells?

Comment: Human sex cells, or [gametes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamete), have 23 chromosomes - they are [haploid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ploidy#Haploid_and_monoploid). Somatic cells are [diploid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ploidy#Diploid) - they have 23 *pairs* of chromosomes, for a total of 46.

Comment: To add on @MattDMo's comment, each chromosome can be made of a single or two [chromatids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromatid) depending on the phase of the [cell cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cell_cycle) you are in.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Terminology is what is holding you back. 
What chromosome implies depends on context, i.e. is it replicated or not.

In Meiosis. Gametes arise from Germline cells that have 23 **PAIRS** of chromosomes. That means, that while there are 23 different chromosomes they come in doubles/pairs. This is the typical X like shape we think about when we hear chromosomes.
Another way, chromosome can means either 1X or 2 single chromatid

MEIOSIS I -- 23X chromosome pairs are duplicate and end up as 46X chromosome pairs (46 pairs of X OR, 92 separate chromatid)

These 46X are divided equally among two daughter cells just like in mitosis. Where now each daughter cell receives 23X = 23 pairs.

MEIOSIS II. The daughter cells in end of Meiosis I divide without DNA replication and the 23 pairs are split among 2 new cells. So now each new daughter cell (in total 4) has 23 individual chromatid (individual chromosomes)
and these are the gametes.

When the gametes fertilize to form a zygote, the zugote product ends up 24X each.

Each X contains, 1 chromatid (|) from the father and 1 chromatid {|} from the mother.

Haploid means once copy of each chromosome. 
23
Diploid means two copies chromosomes or 23X

Ref
- Allison Q.N,.(2015), Freeman Biological Science.

Comment: *`Gametes have 23 PAIRS of chromosomes.`* No. Gametes have 23 chromosomes - they are haploid. Somatic cells are diploid - they have 23 pairs.

Comment: Cheers MattDMo cleared it up.